# How to create an Excel Name/Value pair dropdown

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the following columns

```
A     | B
Name  | Value
One   | 1
Two   | 2
Three | 3
```

In column C, I want to have a Validation Drop-down list which shows the concatenation of Name and Value (i.e. One - 1, Two - 2, etc.). 
When the user makes a selection (i.e. Two - 2), only the data in the Value column populates the cell (i.e. 2).

How do I accomplish this feat?

Comment: a question just like this was asked last week (don't have link OTOMH). This is not possible in Excel, except with the use of VBA. Are you open to a VBA solution?

Answer (score 1):

With data like:

[image]

Place the following VBA macro in a standard module and run it:

```
Sub DV_Maker()
   Dim i As Long
   Dim s As String

   For i = 2 To 4
      s = s & "," & Cells(i, 1) & " - " & Cells(i, 2)
   Next i
   s = Mid(s, 2)

   With Range("C2:C4").Validation
   .Delete
           .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
             xlBetween, Formula1:=s
           .IgnoreBlank = True
           .InCellDropdown = True
           .InputTitle = ""
           .ErrorTitle = ""
           .InputMessage = ""
           .ErrorMessage = ""
           .ShowInput = True
           .ShowError = False
   End With
End Sub
```

It will setup Data Validation for cells **C2**, **C3**, and **C4**.  Then place this Event Macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   Dim rng As Range
   Set rng = Range("S2:C4")

   If Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
   Application.EnableEvents = False
      Target.Value = Split(Target.Value, " - ")(1)
   Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

The event macro will remove the text from the cell after the data has been entered.